# Trying to extract a substring from a major strings containing special characters

Tags: r, string, substring

I am trying to extract a substring from the following strings:

```
x <- "U1+ ^Eucalyptus baxteri s.s.,Eucalyptus viminalis subsp. cygnetensis\\^tree\\7\\i;U2 Acacia melanoxylon,Banksia marginata\\tree\\7\\i;M1 ^Leucopogon parviflorus,Spyridium parvifolium,Leucopogon lanceolatus var. lanceolatus\\^shrub\\4\\r;M2 Xanthorrhoea minor subsp. lutea,Pteridium esculentum,Billardiera scandens\\fern,grass-tree,vine\\3\\i;G1 ^Veronica calycina,Brunonia australis,Deyeuxia quadriseta,Dianella revoluta var. revoluta s.l.,Dichelachne crinita\\rush,^forb,tussock grass,other grass,sedge\\2\\c;G2 Lagenophora stipitata,Luzula meridionalis,Lomandra nana,Pimelea humilis,Acrotriche serrulata\\rush,heath shrub,forb,vine,sedge\\1\\i"
```

I am wishing to extract `6\c` as a subset that comes immediately after `\^tree` however, I am facing issues usisng `sub()` function and thats probably related to the special characters existing in the main string. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your code such that it uses an actual valid R character literal.

Comment: check the comment above. One way to do this is to run `x` in your console, copy it and paste it here, or just do `dput(x)` copy the output and paste it here(in your question)

Comment: @onyambu I think I only forgot to put the quotation marks on both sides! The string is as you see. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try running that in R, it cannot work. because there is nothing like `\^`.  `\c` etc. Your string is incorrect. Its not just a matter of missing quotation marks, but rather its not a correct string. Unless you escape the backslash

Comment: unless you claim its a literal string then you could use `r"(...)"`

Comment: @onyambu When I `dput()` this I get the same thing and yes that is what you get from `r"(...)"` Also, this is only one row from 400,000 rows. I am just trying to figure out how this is done so that I can develop a function for it to apply to all rows. If it had no `\^` etc it would be too easy to post it here!

Comment: okay copy the output of `dput` and include that in your question. As the question stands, no one can create `x` in their R console. as it throws syntax errors.

Comment: try doing `sub(".*?\\^tree([^;]+).*", "\\1", x)`

Comment: @onyambu I just edited the question by the output from `dput()`. Let me know if that works!

Comment: @onyambu What you set as response works fine. Post it as an answer and I am happy to accept. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sub(".*?\\^tree([^;]+).*", "\\1", x)
[1] "\\7\\i"
```

---

Note that the double backslash is just a single literal backslash.

```
cat(sub(".*?\\^tree([^;]+).*", "\\1", x))
\7\i
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain this a bit so that I can apply to similar strings with different special characters?